# Why does my grouped summarize() take so long?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am processing a large data set and I keep getting to this one place where R will just run forever (or freeze, I can't tell). I would appreciate any help making this step more efficient. I've tried to make this as simple as possible, but this is my first question so let me know if you need anything else

#### Example

My data were generated from RFID tags worn by people during social interactions. Each row is an interaction between two individuals (a dyad) for one second. I've arranged the data frame by the datetime and then used data.table's `rleid()` to create a unique identifier for the duration of each interaction (figuring that part out took me months). The data look something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
# data represent interactions between a pair of nodes such that each row is one second of one interaction for a specific dyad (`id`) 
df <- tibble(datetime = as_datetime(1511870400:1511870409)) %>%
  mutate(id = c(rep("x_1", 4), rep("x_2", 3), rep("x_1", 2), "x_2"), rl = rleid(id))# rleid sets a unique numeric identifier for each interaction or run of events (consecutive rows with shared ID)
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    datetime            id       rl
#>    <dttm>              <chr> <int>
#>  1 2017-11-28 12:00:00 x_1       1
#>  2 2017-11-28 12:00:01 x_1       1
#>  3 2017-11-28 12:00:02 x_1       1
#>  4 2017-11-28 12:00:03 x_1       1
#>  5 2017-11-28 12:00:04 x_2       2
#>  6 2017-11-28 12:00:05 x_2       2
#>  7 2017-11-28 12:00:06 x_2       2
#>  8 2017-11-28 12:00:07 x_1       3
#>  9 2017-11-28 12:00:08 x_1       3
#> 10 2017-11-28 12:00:09 x_2       4
```

Where `id` refers to a unique dyad (or pair of individuals) and `rl` refers to a single interaction. Interactions varied in duration and time. This is as far as I've gotten, because R never finishes the following code each time I try to run it with my data (224,970,752 rows). I've tried leaving it overnight, but R is still processing when I come back.

```r
# grouped summarize to get the start_datetime, end_datetime, & duration of each interaction/event
events <- df %>% 
  group_by(rl) %>%
  summarize(start_date = min(datetime),
            end_date = max(datetime),
            duration = int_length(interval(start_date, end_date)))
events
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>      rl start_date          end_date            duration
#>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>  
#> 1     1 2017-11-28 12:00:00 2017-11-28 12:00:03        3  
#> 2     2 2017-11-28 12:00:04 2017-11-28 12:00:06        2  
#> 3     3 2017-11-28 12:00:07 2017-11-28 12:00:08        1  
#> 4     4 2017-11-28 12:00:09 2017-11-28 12:00:09        0
```

The result of this first step should give me the start datetime, end datetime, and duration of each interaction. The next step will be to join the new `start_date`, `end_date`, & `duration` columns to the original data, using `rl` as the key.

```r
# join events to df so each row represents a single interaction with start_date, end_date, & duration
df %>% 
  right_join(events, by = "rl") %>% 
  distinct(rl, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-datetime)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   id       rl start_date          end_date            duration
#>   <chr> <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
#> 1 x_1       1 2017-11-28 12:00:00 2017-11-28 12:00:03 3 secs  
#> 2 x_2       2 2017-11-28 12:00:04 2017-11-28 12:00:06 2 secs  
#> 3 x_1       3 2017-11-28 12:00:07 2017-11-28 12:00:08 1 secs  
#> 4 x_2       4 2017-11-28 12:00:09 2017-11-28 12:00:09 0 secs
```

Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)

This is the final result I'm looking for, where each row represents one **uninterrupted** interaction (edge) between two individuals.

Comment: Does your real date time information start as an integer? Lubridate is painfully slow, why do all those conversions and dispatch two slow lubridate methods (`int_length` and `interval`) if the data already starts as an integer?

Comment: To add to that, try using `duration = difftime(end_date, start_date, "second")` instead `int_length(interval`.

Comment: @IanCampbell: Unfortunately, the date times come as date times (i.e., "2010-03-14 07:00:00"). Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: Thanks @AndreWildberg. I ran it with `difftime()` and it actually worked. Thank you so much! Should I close this question?

Comment: You can add an edit at the bottom of your question and describe shortly what solved it for you. That helps others who might run into the same problem.

Comment: Or, if you want, I can post an answer and add a bit of benchmarking, just based on `lubridate` and `difftime`

Comment: Thanks @andrewildberg, that would be great. I added an edit but I'm sure your answer will be more helpful for others to follow...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, replacing 
`duration = int_length(interval(start_date, end_date))`

with 
`duration = difftime(end_date, start_date, "second")`

should give a significant speed up.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  lubridate = {df %>% 
                 group_by(rl) %>% 
                 summarize(start_date = min(datetime), 
                   end_date = max(datetime), 
                   duration = int_length(interval(start_date, end_date)))}, 
  difftime = {df %>% 
                group_by(rl) %>% 
                summarize(start_date = min(datetime), 
                  end_date = max(datetime), 
                  duration = difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "secs"))}, 
times = 1000)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 lubridate 13.76997 13.93371 16.56413 14.30699 16.56841 293.7661  1000   b
  difftime 10.83277 10.94778 12.57737 11.15954 12.60073  58.4128  1000  a
```